# flexgrid custom data binding

Tags: vb6, msflexgrid

Is it possible to bind a msflexgrid/mshflexgrid to a custom datasource in vb6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course you can.  This was one of the new features in VB6.

See [Using the DataGrid Control with a Class Module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231247%28VS.60%29.aspx) which is for a DataGrid but the same thing works with the FlexGrids.

You can create data-aware Classes and UserControls, or you can create an OLEDB Simple provider.

Comment: Thank you.the link is very useful and is similar to custom data binding in .net framework.